# (gRPC .Net) Importing ProtoA (.proto) file defined in Project A into protoB (.proto) file defined in Project B

Tags: grpc, proto

I tried a Way in using proto files in which

1. I defined rpc components in proto B in Project B

   Exmaple : rpc Line (RequestData) returns (ResponseInfoBase);
2. I defined message in Proto A which is in project A(different project)

   Example : message RequestData {
   string  Data = 1 ; }

message ResponseInfoBase {
string Data = 1; }
My question is am I able to import ProtoA to ProtoB?

Comment: Are these two projects belong to the same solution (.sln)? Please advise.

Comment: yes.they are being used in same solution

Comment: Good morning. I have added the solution. Please review and let me know if it works? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Source Code URL:** https://github.com/vishipayyallore/speaker_series/tree/master/GRpcDemos/SimpleGRpcDemo

**ForHoldingMessages.csproj** This holds only messages.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\AddressBookMessages.proto" GrpcServices="None" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**College.Service.csproj** This holds the rpc method and uses the message defined in ForHoldingMessagaes.csproj.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\ForHoldingMessages\Protos\AddressBookMessages.proto" GrpcServices="None">
      <Link>Protos\AddressBookMessages.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    <Protobuf Include="..\College.Service\Protos\AddressBook.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="..">
    </Protobuf>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**College.ServiceClient.csproj** This is the gRPC Client application which uses the protos from both the projects and invokes the RPC method defined in College.Service.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\College.Service\Protos\AddressBook.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="..">
      <Link>Protos\AddressBook.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="..\ForHoldingMessages\Protos\AddressBookMessages.proto" GrpcServices="Client">
      <Link>Protos\AddressBookMessages.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Image for additional Reference:

[image]

Comment: tried every possible way

used import,used proto as connected service,gave file path

Comment: Did you add import statements inside the .proto file where you are importing?

Comment: main.proto file. add **import "child.proto";**

Comment: I have updated the solution. Please review and let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the proto file and .csproj contents only the main content? Also the project folder structure from Solution Explorer.

Comment: i wanna use protoA in core project so that i can use it in  local projects

Comment: @RaghuRavuri, Give me a few minutes. I will create a sample and check-in the code into GitHub. Many thanks.

Comment: @RaghuRavuri, I am done with the code. I will publish it to my GitHub Repository in a few minutes. Many thanks.

Comment: @RaghuRavuri, I have updated the solution and also published the URL of the code.

Comment: tried exactly the same.but still same error persists

Comment: @RaghuRavuri, Good morning. Did you get a chance to get my code and compile it on your local box? Please try that whenever you have a couple of minutes. Many thanks.

Comment: ,Went through your code.Figured out what my problem Was!Thanks a billion.

Comment: still have a issue though,while importing proto file from one solution's .cs project to second solutions .cs project.Used the same method you did in your sample project but doesnt work that way.Any idea how to import btw different solutions??

Thanks

Comment: @RaghuRavuri, If it is OK with you I will give (solution to solution) .proto file import a shot this weekend. Please advise. I feel technically it should be possible. Let me give that a shot this weekend.

Comment: .tried all the possibilities to import .proto b/w solutions,but not able to do that.if you have any hacks pls let me know

Comment: @RaghuRavuri, Sorry I could not spend time on the weekend. I will give this a shot tomorrow and let you know. Many thanks.

Comment: @ Viswanatha Swamy,Figured out a way to use proto accross solutions,But thanks for the Root Idea